# Not able to call a function in the controller after using force_download

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my code.

```
$data = file_get_contents("gpsfile/".$name); // Read the file's contents
    force_download($name, $data);
$this->viewall();
```

If i comment `force_download(),` `$this->viewall` function call works'
Is force_download() not letting call.. please help

Comment: `$this->load->helper('download');` have u used the helper

Comment: use if(force_download()){$this->view_all();}

Comment: Yes, I have used the helper.

Comment: @raheelshan that doesn't work either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call any functions after using `force_download`, As per the helper, the `force_download` exits so that nothing else after it gets executed. So you need to use some javascript in your view file for downloading the file and then calling required controller function after download is complete.